# Replace elements in a numpy ndarray accessed via index array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to replace certain columns in a multi-dimensional array with the value that I have. I tried the following.

```
cols_to_replace = np.array([1, 2, 2, 2])

original_array = np.array([[[255, 101,  51],
    [255, 101, 153],
    [255, 101, 255]],

   [[255, 153,  51],
    [255, 153, 153],
    [255, 153, 255]],

   [[255, 203,  51],
    [255, 204, 153],
    [255, 205, 255]],

   [[255, 255,  51],
    [255, 255, 153],
    [255, 255, 255]]], dtype=int)
```

Replace just the cols with `(0, 0, 255)`

I was hoping that I can index all the columns using the array `cols_to_replace`

```
 original_array[:, cols_to_replace] = (0, 0, 255)
```

This gave a wrong answer!

**Unexpected output.**

```
array([[[255, 101,  51],
    [  0,   0, 255],
    [  0,   0, 255]],

   [[255, 153,  51],
    [  0,   0, 255],
    [  0,   0, 255]],

   [[255, 203,  51],
    [  0,   0, 255],
    [  0,   0, 255]],

   [[255, 255,  51],
    [  0,   0, 255],
    [  0,   0, 255]]])
```

**My expected output is**

```
array([[[255, 101,  51],
    [  0,   0, 255],
    [255, 101, 255]],

   [[255, 153,  51],
    [255, 153, 153],
    [  0,   0, 255]],

   [[255, 203,  51],
    [255, 204, 153],
    [  0,   0, 255]],

   [[255, 255,  51],
    [255, 255, 153],
    [  0,   0, 255]]])
```

- What is really happening?
- How do I accomplish what I am trying to do (that is access, col 1, col 2, col 2, col 2 in each of these rows and replace the values.
- If I want to delete those columns, is there a `numpy` way to do it?

Comment: try: `original_array[np.arange(cols_to_replace.size), cols_to_replace] = 0, 0, 255`

Comment: @PaulPanzer - That was it. What's happening and why is `:` to access all the rows not working? You could list down as an answer for me to accept it.

Comment: @PaulPanzer - If I have to delete those cols, is there a way?

Comment: The reason is that advanced indexing and slice indexing are evaluated "separately", by changing `:` to an `arange` we switch the zeroth dimension to advanced indexing, so that cols_to_replace` can act level by level. - deleting is a bit more tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected output is produced by:

```
>>> original_array[np.arange(cols_to_replace.size), cols_to_replace] = 0, 0, 255
```

This differs from your original approach because advanced indexing and slice indexing are evaluated "separately". By changing `:` to an `arange` we switch the zeroth dimension to advanced indexing, so that `cols_to_replace` is paired element-by-element with `0, 1, 2, ...` in the zeroth coordinate.

You can delete your selection using a mask like so:

```
>>> mask = np.ones(original_array.shape[:2], bool)
>>> mask[np.arange(cols_to_replace.size), cols_to_replace] = False
>>> original_array[mask].reshape(original_array.shape[0], -1, original_array.shape[2])
array([[[255, 101,  51],
        [255, 101, 255]],

       [[255, 153,  51],
        [255, 153, 153]],

       [[255, 203,  51],
        [255, 204, 153]],

       [[255, 255,  51],
        [255, 255, 153]]])
```

Comment: Very interesting. Feels like gymnastics, when using the mask feature. I was tempted to do with via loops.

Comment: Also, is there a reference to this "because advanced indexing and slice indexing are evaluated "separately"." Or did you know this from your experience?

Comment: There is [Combining advanced and basic indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in the numpy docs.